# ulimit -n not persisting, tried everything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I need to increase ulimit -n on Ubuntu 12.04. It's currently:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

(1024 soft, 4096 hard)

In /etc/security/limits.conf I have:

```
root soft nofile 10240
root hard nofile 10240
```

In /etc/pam.d/login, /etc/pam.d/common-session, /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive I have

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

However, ulimit -n keeps resetting to 1024. I need to increase it as I use Node.js / socket.io with forever and the limit is limiting the maximum of concurrent visitors / connections.

Comment: Keeps resetting when? At reboot? Every hour? Randomly?

Comment: @gladoscc - Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 1):

How do you start your program?

Try to wrap the start code for your program with something like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "ulimit -n 4096; exec /usr/bin/node /PATH_TO/YOUR_PROGRAM.js"
```

Comment: I'm using forever to start the program.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like /etc/limits.d/* ?
Have you tried turning SELinux off (if you have it turned on)?

Comment: No. I don't have selinux.

Answer (score -1):

Add `ulimit -n 10240` to /root/.bashrc

Comment: This'll affect forever / node.js?

Comment: It will persist forever but only affect things running in bash using root's profile and executing the .bashrc.

Comment: You shouldn't really be running node as root in production

Answer (score -1):

The same problem exists in Debian 8, when I`m running Redis via the init script it came with. Lost 16 hours writing configs & rebooting trying to get past the limit of 1020 connections running as non-root. I`m going to run it as root. 
AFAIK the apache server is working this way: starts as root, sets the process limits & drops the uid to www-data.